# How to propagate data validation to other rows?

Tags: validation, google-sheets, autofill

Sheet `Ranges`:

[image]

Sheet `Work`:

[image]

In sheet `Ranges` in cells `A1:A5` I have some values, let's say: `One`, `Two`, `Three`, `Four`, `Five`. In cell `B1` I have the following formula: `=ARRAYFORMULA(transpose(if(Work!$A1<>"";$A$1:$A$5;"")))` which fills cells `B1:F1` with above mentioned values based on whether the cell `A1` in sheet `Work` is non-empty.

Next, I've selected cells `B1:F1` and then using fill-handle dragged the selection down to cover range `B1:F10`. This copied the above range but each row now depends on the corresponding row in sheet `Work`.

Basically, I've created a list of ranges of data that are only filled when certains cells in another sheet are non-empty.

Finally, in sheet `Work` I've added data validation for cell `B1` with a dropdown list:
`Ranges!B1:F1`

What this does is creates a dropdown list in this cell with values: `One`, `Two`, `Three`, `Four`, `Five` but only if cell `A1` is non-empty!

Now for my question - I would like to propagate this data validation to other rows (1 - 10) with fill-handle but so that the dropdown list depends on a different cell/row in each case. **But the fill-handle just copies the validation rule from the first row in each case.** (You can see in the 2nd picture that even for rows with empty cell in column `A` there are still dropdowns with values.

How can I propagate this without having to change the cell ranges in data validation rules manually in each case?

Comment: I've used a script to do that (so that's kind of like doing it manually... :P). If anyone knows a way to do it without using scripts please share.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since no one proposed anything better I'm closing it with my solution from the comment. I've used a script that sets the data validation for each cell separately. I'm not posting code since my actual sheet is quite different from this example and I would have to rewrite the whole thing.

This solution is far from ideal, mostly because you have to spend time googling the syntax and functions and also not everyone will even want to have scripts in their sheet. But apparently there's nothing better.

It's worth mentioning that fill-handle does what I want in Excel. I've tried creating this sheet in excel and opening it in google sheets but was disappointed to find out that the data validation rules were lost/broken in the process.

Answer (score -2):

```js
function a(str)
{
 if(str.uname.value=="")
 {
  document.getElementById("msg1").innerHTML="! Plz Enter Username";
  str.uname.focus();
  return false;
 }
 if(str.pass.value=="")
 {
  document.getElementById("msg1").innerHTML="Plz Enter Password...";
  str.pass.focus();
  return false;
 }
 if((str.pass.value.length<3)||(str.pass.value.length>8))
 {
  document.getElementById("msg1").innerHTML="Plz Enter Password 3 to 8";
  str.pass.focus();
  return false;
 }
 
}
```

```html
<?php
if(isset($_REQUEST['submit']))
 {
  $uname=$_REQUEST['uname'];
  
  }?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="valjs.js">
</script>
</head>

<body>
<form method="post" name="frm"  onsubmit="return a(this)" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<table align="center" border="2"  cellpadding="5px" cellspacing="0px" border="1px">
<tr>
<td><span style="color:#FF0000">* </span>username</td>
<td><input type="text" name="uname" id="uname" />
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Password</td>
<td><input type="password" name="pass" id="pass" />
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Click" />
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
<h4 align="center"><span id="msg1" style="color:#FF0000" >
</span>
</h4>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How does this have anything to do with my question?